# Revenue Cat error thrown in Purchases.configure(withAPIKey: "my_api_key")

Tags: swift, xcode, revenuecat

I am simply trying to configure Revenue Cat in my App Delegate's `didFinishLaunchingOptions` method with `Purchases.configure(withAPIKey: "my_api_key")` (as explained in the [docs](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/configuring-sdk)), but it keeps printing the following error...

`‼️ Error fetching offerings - The operation couldn’t be completed. (RevenueCat.OfferingsManager.Error error 1.)`

Is it because my api key could be wrong? I followed the docs by uploading a shared secret from my App Store connect, and the api key I am using is from the bottom of the following image called "Public API Key".

This seems like such a simple task..

[image]

**[EDIT]** Or could it be my offering isn't fully set up? I tried, but it still looks like this:

[image]

And after clicking "offerings" it says this:

[image]

I did add an "Entitlement" and "Product" though, so not sure why it looks like that.

Comment: Do you have your Products, Offerings and Entitlements setup?

Comment: @Asteroid I thought so.. see my edit above for more info on that.

Comment: Your error message "RevenueCat.OfferingsManager.Error error 1" suggests something about the offerings not the API key. Have Products, Offerings and Entitlements setup properly first. That's my guess

Comment: Okay thank you. I'll try that and keep you (and anyone else in the future) updated.

Comment: @Asteroid Yeah it was my offerings that weren't set up right. Thanks for your help